# wkhtmltopdf windows error

Tags: php, windows, pdf, exec, wkhtmltopdf

I'm having problems with `wkhtmltopdf` under Windows. `safe_mode` is off and the folder's permission are ok. Here is an example:

```
exec('wkhtmltopdf.exe --margin-left 0mm --margin-right 0mm --margin-top 0mm --margin-bottom 0mm --page-size A4 --zoom 2.1 text.html test.pdf');
```

The first time the PDF gets generated, but to make it work again I have to restart apache.

Comment: tip: PHP will convert `/` to `\ ` for you, so you don't need to double-backslash paths in php. `c:/wamp/www/local/....` is perfectly acceptable and PHP will take care of the details for you. Save yourself from your bad case of "leaning toothpick syndrome"

Comment: I don't think PHP converts forward slashes to backslashes. Windows actually accepts both natively.

Answer (score 0):

see if wkhtmltopdf is still running using your task manager after you complete first run.
if it is running close it and try generating PDF

Post you apache error log